# Should a tag that gives insight into a problem be removed if it is the actual problem?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at this question: [Get folders names inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23156310/691711) and it seems as though the problem is that the OP is trying to mix PHP and JavaScript, which you can't explicitly do without a intermediary layer between the two languages.

The original question had only the `JavaScript` tag but an edit added the `PHP` tag which was later removed by another editor.  Should the tag have been removed?  PHP is a part of the problem in the question.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the OP is actually trying to solve the issue of getting PHP and JavaScript to mix. It looks the two languages were mixed in a naive way when the solution here would be to just use JavaScript.

Comment: If the OP had been looking for a PHP answer the question would have been terribly broad - given that the OP isn't going to be able to implement any snippet of code. His attempted solution (the only bit that contains php) makes the question worse rather than better. So in that particular case the PHP tag adds nothing.